# Is it possible to rearrange an array with constant memory overhead?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, in-place

I stumbled upon this while reading some StackOverflow questions but could not find a satisfying answer.

Suppose we have an `array A` of length `n` containing its indexes from `0` to `n-1` in a random fashion. Is it possible to rearrange the array so that its outcome is `A[ A[i] ]` with constant `O(1)` memory overhead?

Example:

```
A = [ 3, 2, 0, 1 ]
rearrange( A )
A = [ 1, 0, 3, 2 ]
```

If it is possible an outline of the algorithm would be nice. Otherwise an explanation why it is not possible. Since inplace sorting is a thing maybe this works similar.

Clarification:
If you do not have the memory constraint the algorithm is trivial:

```
A = [ 3, 2, 0, 1 ]
A_r = Array_of_size( A )
for i = 0 to Arraysize - 1
   A_r[ i ] = A[ A[i] ]
```

Outcome `A_r = [ 1, 0, 3, 2]`

Comment: What is the logic to rearrange the array?

Comment: Sure, you can rearrange the array in place ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm)). To write the logic is up to you, but you don't need an extra array for it.

Comment: @hellow arranging the array in place doesn't seem so obvious for this specific case

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any trivial solution (but in most languages tricks should be possible as we mostly have to know for each value whether it has been changed... and most often there's one bit free somewhere in the values)

Comment: Indeed the solution (if there exists any, which I doubt) is not trivial. I would disqualify languages tricks, because imho finding a free bit somewhere in the values is somehow equivalent to using a `O(n)` piece of array.

Comment: @m.raynal For the trick, I was referring to cases when the free bit can be determined from the value type or from a known range of the values. Of course it's not an answer in the general case and I won't write it down as an answer. But most real cases of this problem don't really appear exactly this way and can be solved with this trick in practice.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Definitely agree with you, the first thing that came to my mind was "O(1) overhead ? No, there *must* be some unused bits in this array !"

Comment: @m.raynal see trincot's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible.

The input array consists of values that are indexes in the same array, and so it is a collection of one or more cycles. Each cycle can have 1 or more elements.

The mutation of the array can best be performed cycle by cycle, as the change in one cycle would only require a temporary storage of one value in that cycle, while the "next" value is copied into the "previous" slot until the whole cycle has been visited and the temporary value can be put in the last slot.

One of the things to consider is that after a cycle has mutated like that, it might not result in a cycle of the same length. For instance, if a cycle has length 4, then the mutation will result in 2 cycles of 2 values. More generally, a cycle with even length will divide into two cycles. Odd cycles keep their length, and just have their order changed.

Once a cycle has mutated, the algorithm should never revisit any of its values "accidentally" applying the mutation to that cycle again.

One way to ensure that this does not happen is to only apply the mutation to a cycle when its *rightmost* element is visited in a left-to-right iteration. This is the key of the proposed algorithm. That way one can be sure that the elements in this cycle will never be visited again, and will not be mutated again.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript. You can enter the array values in an input field. The algorithm is executed at every change to the input:

```js
function arrange(a) {
    function isRightmostOfCycle(i) {
        let j = a[i]
        while (j < i) j = a[j]
        return j == i
    }

    function updateCycle(i) {
        let saved = a[i]
        let k = i
        for (let j = a[i]; j < i; j = a[j]) {
            a[k] = a[j]
            k = j
        }
        a[k] = saved
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (isRightmostOfCycle(i)) updateCycle(i)
    }
    return a
}

// I/O handling
let input = document.querySelector("input")
let output = document.querySelector("pre");
(input.oninput = function () {
    let a = (input.value.match(/\d+/g) || []).map(Number)
    // Check whether input is valid
    let i = a.findIndex((_,i) => !a.includes(i))
    output.textContent = i < 0 ? arrange(a) : "Missing " + i
})();
```

```css
input { width: 100% }
```

```html
Array values: <input value="2,0,5,7,6,4,1,8,3"><p>
Result: 
<pre></pre>
```

The check whether an index represents the rightmost element of a cycle has a time complexity of *O(n)*, so the total time complexity is *O(n²)*. The additional space complexity however is constant.

Comment: As this answer is a more thoroughly explained and bug-fixed version of another answer, it needs to be properly attributde, as both the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) and the question [When is using an other poster's content plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251389/when-is-using-an-other-posters-content-plagiarism/) points out. The standard in the scientific community, is to attribute others work and highlight your own contributions. I am not sure whether simple bug-fixes (even when hard to find) is enough for a new answer, but that is not up to me.

Comment: @Ninetails, I don't think that is appropriate here. Your answer was on a wrong track as I pointed out, and after I had answered and commented further on it, you first commented that it then was questionable it could be solved in O(1), but then later deleted that comment and revised your answer to use the same key idea as mine. This is more than just a "bug fix" -- it is a different approach.

Comment: The question [When is using an other poster's content plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251389/when-is-using-an-other-posters-content-plagiarism/) specifically deals also with the case where the original post was erroneous, and judges that attribution is still required when using even part of the solution. The question [answers-which-are-wrong](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267772/answers-which-are-wrong) points toward the desired behavior of fixing old wrong answers when a correction have been published.

Comment: Furthermore, you are in an attribution bind, since either the 2 approaches are destinct (very unlikely, since most of the structure of the code is the same, large parts of the algorithm, analysis and the explaination makes explicit use of terms as described as variable names in the older answer), in which case retroactive changes inspired from your answer would still constitude a different answer, or the answers are build upon each other, in which case you are required to provide attribution to the older answer.

Comment: All true, but I was not using your content, so it does not apply.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible if we combine hole based chain swaps and that we can regonize a cycle in the permutation by the lowest or highest position in the array. We simply for each position only chain through the cycle if the position we are looking at is the highest in that cycle. The hole based method ensure that we only use constant space to perform the rotation of the cycle. The downside is that the time complexity becomes `O(n^2)`. Here is a simple python implementation:

```py
def is_start(array, index):
    start = index
    index = array[index]
    while start > index:
        index = array[index]
    return start == index


def rotate(array, index):
    start = index
    next = array[index]
    hole = next
    while start > next:
        array[index] = array[next]
        index = next
        next = array[index]
    array[index] = hole


def rearrange(array):
    for index in range(len(array)):
        if is_start(array, index):
            rotate(array, index)
```

> ### Bug-fix
>
> (@trincot) pointed out that using the last entry of the cycle instead of the first ensures that we never investigate possibly corrupted cycles.
>   Effect: Changing the dirrection of inequalities from `start < index` to `start > index`.

Comment: You make the wrong assumption that a cycle -- once you have mutated it -- remains a cycle of the same length. This is not true for *even* cycles, and so your algo will not work. For instance an input of `[1,2,3,0]` should give `[2,3,0,1]` as result, but your code gives `[2,1,0,3]`.

Comment: (@ trincot) I did miss that rotations can break the cycles, and I have implemented the bug-fixes suggested by you, so that the solution should not be incorrect anymore.